# QCustomPlot linker

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, opencv, qcustomplot

I would like to use the features of QCustomPlot to draw some results from my openCV projects.

I didn't find a way to include QCustomPlot to my Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. I have included or course the cpp and h file into my project. But, I think what is still missing for me is regarding its linker and the additional dependencies (.lib file)

```
1>moc_ex4.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall ex4::plot_graphs(void)" (?plot_graphs@ex4@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "private: static void __cdecl ex4::qt_static_metacall(class QObject *,enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_static_metacall@ex4@@CAXPAVQObject@@W4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)
1>C:\Users\310114602\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ex4_120313\Win32\Debug\\ex4.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I searched for it but no results.

Where shall I download it?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you either didn't [moc your cpp file](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/moc.html) or you simply forgot to compile and link against the moc generated .cpp file.